# Python - regex ends with specific image extension

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape links with a specific class with `BeautifulSoup` and want to exclude images like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<html><body><a class="link" 
  href="http://test/file.html">right</a><br><a class="link" 
  href="/test/file.jpg">false</a><br><a class="link" 
  href="/test/file.img">false</a><br><a class="link" 
  href="http://test/file.html">right</a><br></html>''')

for a in soup.findAll('a', 
     attrs={"class":"link", "href":re.compile('.*\.(?!jpg$|img$)[^.]+')}):
 print(a.text)
```

Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Why do you think there is anything wrong with it? When I run your snippet, I get `right` and `right` on two different lines. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: Using a regex with negative lookaheads to filter your results is very error prone. Even if you think your expression is correct, chances are there are corner cases that you are missing.